# Redirecting to another URL only in IE(Internet Explorer)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to hit the URL in the browser especially IE(Internet Explorer) for the first time when i try to hit the URL afer clearing all the cookies, it is redirecting to a home page. For example, first time I try to hit users page but it fails to load and it goes to dashboard page. This happens only at the first time of loading the URL after clearing all the cookies. I can see this issue  only in test server not in local, because in test server only there is an authentication, when it fails to load it is some thing like going for authentication and it redirects to home page.

I can't able to find why it fails for the first time in IE only. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Front end : Angular 5
Backend : Java

Comment: Does your application use cookies?

Comment: Cookies not using in application, After clearing the history the issue occurs.@David

Comment: Check your guards and use of local storage maybe